# Java replace curly brackets string using replaceAll when the value is in variable, java 8

Tags: java, string, java-8, str-replace, replaceall

I have a variable:

```
String content = "<xxx.xx.name>xxx.xxx.com:111</xxx.xx.name>";
String destination = "\\$\\{VAR\\}";
String source = "xxx.xxx.com:111";
content = content.replaceAll(source, destination);
```

Result:

```
result = {IllegalArgumentException@781} Method threw 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' exception.
detailMessage = "Illegal group reference"
cause = {IllegalArgumentException@781} "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference"
stackTrace = {StackTraceElement[5]@783} 
suppressedExceptions = {Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList@773}  size = 0
```

But if I do:

```
content = content.replaceAll(source,"\\$\\{VAR\\}");
```

all is working fine. How can I mimic or fix the replaceAll?

Comment: Both work fine for me; can't reproduce the issue. (Java 11.0.6)

Comment: java 8 is what im working with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation of [`String.replaceAll(String, String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)):

> Note that backslashes (\) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string ***may*** cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string;

Emphasis on the *may*, depending on your Java version this may fail (though I fail to reproduce your problem with Java 8, 11, 12, [15](https://jdk.java.net/15/) and even the early access [Java 16](https://jdk.java.net/16/))

You can use [`Matcher.quoteReplacement(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)) to escape your \ and $ chars in the replacement string, as described later on in the javadoc:

> Use Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String) to suppress the special meaning of these characters, if desired.

So change your code to this (assuming you want to replace the contents with `${VAR}` and not with `\${VAR\}`):

```
String content = "<xxx.xx.name>xxx.xxx.com:111</xxx.xx.name>";
String destination = Matcher.quoteReplacement("${VAR}");
String source = "xxx.xxx.com:111";
content = content.replaceAll(source, destination);
```

Which results in:

```
<xxx.xx.name>${VAR}</xxx.xx.name>
```

#### [DEMO](https://ideone.com/uCmyPc)

Comment: Do you have an idea why apparently only Java 15 "fails" here?

Comment: @akuzminykh ernest_k commented this, but since then have removed their comment, I checked with the latest build from Java 15 and was not able to reproduce this problem.

Comment: Yeah, I also got curious after the comment about Java 15 working. I think it's not likely that a basic method like `String#replaceAll` breaks because of a new Java version. If that's the case, I think it's interesting why.

Comment: @akuzminykh I guess, it’s not `replaceAll` but the processing of the string literals that changed as a side effect of adding that [text blocks feature](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/378).